# Global Array not Appending Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a global array called cannonArray that I initialized before any function. I have a touchesBegan function that appends values to the array. When I print the array from within the touchesBegan function, it prints perfectly. However, when I print the array from the didMoveToViewFunction, nothing updates and it simply prints [] (and doesn't change as it should because it is global). I also have another function called createEnemies that is on a timer and it has the same problem (prints proper appended array within the function, but not in another one). Thanks! :)

```
 var cannonArray = [SKSpriteNode]()
 var enemyArray = [SKSpriteNode]()

 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    enemyCreationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(createEnemies), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    print(enemyArray) //prints empty array
    print(cannonArray) // prints empty array

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    cannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cannon")
    cannon.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    cannon.position = location

    if frameArray[0].contains(location) || frameArray[1].contains(location) {
        print("cant")
    }else {
        self.addChild(cannon)
        self.cannonArray.append(cannon)
        //if i print here it works
    }

}
 @objc func createEnemies() {

    enemiesSpawned += 1

    if enemiesSpawned > enemyNumber {

        enemyCreationTimer.invalidate()

    }else {

        enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: spriteOne.position.x, y: CGFloat(650))
        enemy.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
        self.addChild(enemy)
        enemy.zPosition = 0
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 12.5)
        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        enemy.run(moveEnemies())
        enemyArray.append(enemy)
        //if i print here it works


    }

}
```

Comment: If you can the array through `self.cannonArray` it seems to me it's not global (i.e. a singleton), but an instance variable. It would seem the instance in `didMove(` is something different & gets the arrays initialized to empty ones in its `init`.

Comment: Which prints first?

Comment: @Maysam The empty array in didMoveToView prints first

Comment: mhm, check if you are accessing it from the same thread

Comment: @Maysam they are both part of the same main thread